# 'Error parsing "baseurl = 'repository_url'"' error when trying to install NFS server

Tags: nfs

I'm trying to install an NFS server, but I keep getting this error:

```
root@wsm-ela-inc6:/home/test# yum -y install nfs-utils nfs-utils-lib
Repository 'repository_url': Error parsing config: Error parsing "baseurl = 'repository_url'": URL must be http, ftp, file or https not ""
There are no enabled repos.
Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

It asks to enable repos. How can I do that? Which repos do I have to enable?

I'm working on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu : No "yum repos". ... Ubuntu is using `apt` for package install.

Comment: I used apt but i'm getting this error   .                                                   E: Unable to locate package nfs-utils
E: Unable to locate package nfs-utils-lib